# ¿Como puedo eliminar caracteres especiales y palabras comunes de un archivo txt en python?

Tags: python

```
  #Busqueda y Limpieza
    no_deseados = [',','.','¡','!','¿','?','(',')','"',"'" ," ", "©", "..."]
    for char in no_deseados:
        lista = lista.replace(char, "")

# limpiar palabras comunes
PALABRAS_COMUNES = ["un", "una", "ir", "voy", "de", "que", "the"]
palabras = lista.split()
reformado = ['' if palabra in PALABRAS_COMUNES else palabra for palabra in palabras]
lista = "".join(reformado)
```

Saben por que no me funciona, estas dos partes de mi codigo
agradesco su ayuda

Comment: Define "no me funciona".

Comment: Supongo que el problema venga de que en la lista `no_deseados` tienes al espacio. Si eliminas los espacios de la frase, no podrás después dividir por palabras con `.split()` (el resultado será una larga "palabra" con todo pegado).